# Расчет срока между датами

Tags: java, android

Помогите решить задачу.

Необходимо рассчитать, прошел срок оплаты по штрафу или нет (70 дней).

Допустим сегодня 23 декабря, штраф был 15 октября, программа должна показать прошло 70 дней или нет, и как то это обозначить?

Answer (score 2):

70 дней – это 6048000000 миллисекунд.

Далее элементарно (нумерация месяцев начинается с нуля):

```
private boolean isOverdue(int year, int month, int date, int hour, int minute) {
    Calendar curDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar fineDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    fineDate.set(year, month, date, hour, minute);
    return curDate.getTimeInMillis() - fineDate.getTimeInMillis() > 6048000000L;
}
```

В метод передается дата штрафа. Метод вычисляет количество миллисекунд между датой штрафа и текущей датой, и, в зависимости от результата возвращает соответствующее логическое значение.

Не забудьте добавить проверку на корректность дат.

PS. Если используете Java 8, то, с помощью `java.time`, требуемое можно получить несколько проще.

Answer (score 0):

Советую вам изучить вот эту страничку 
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/date.php